# Testing Exchange Web Service (EWS) url

Tags: c#, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have UI where I have the user enter the Url where I can find the Exchange Web Service(EWS). My application uses EWS to get Free/Busy information but my configuration tool just needs to set it for the user.

For now I am just asking for the host name and building up the Url from there. For example they enter **example.org** as the host and I build **https://example.org/EWS/Exchange.asmx** from that.

I would like to add a test button to ensure the host they entered is reachable by the machine they are configuring. But I'm not sure how simple or complex I need to be to test the service.

Is there any noop or bind I can do to make sure I can establish communication with EWS?

Something like:

```
var serviceUri = new Uri(_textBoxEwsUrl.Text));
var exchangeService = new ExchangeService();
exchangeService.Url = serviceUri;

// what can I call here to test that I can talk to the exchangeService?
exchangeService.????
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the inbox folder of the users mail address. Of course, you would need his credentials to this.

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of operation that results in communication with server can be used as test. Simple binding to any folder or item will throw `ServiceRequestException` or some different type of exception if your url or credentials are incorrect.

Sample code:

```
try
{
    var inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
}
catch(ServiceRequestException e)
{
    //handle exception in some way
}
```